# Find out if a string of text contains a certain letter

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a little website that will tell you if you suck or don't suck by entering your name. (Sort of dumb, but just for learning purposes.)

The way I thought I'd get it to work would be to check if the name has the vowel "a" in it, but I'm not too sure why this code block won't work:

I also think it'd be helpful to know, for future, how to add a query parameter so it would give each name a unique link.

But nevertheless, here is my code. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
function nameSubmit() {
  var nameInput = document.getElementById('checkName');

  if (nameInput.contains('a')) {
    document.getElementById('ans').innerHTML = "You don't suck!"
  } else if (nameInput == "") {
    document.getElementById('ans').innerHTML = "Enter a name please";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('ans').innerHTML = "You suck";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <!-- Links -->
  <link href="assets/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-line-icons/2.4.1/css/simple-line-icons.css">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/97db52ab8f.js"></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- Meta Tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <!-- Title -->
  <title>Website Title</title>
 </head>
<body>

 <input type="text" id="nameCheck">

 <button onclick="nameSubmit()">Submit</button>

 <p id="ans"></p>

<script src="assets/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to do `nameInput.value.contains('a')` and `nameInput.value == ''`... You must check the value of input object, not the input object itself.

Comment: nameCheck vs checkName too and try indexOf("a") !=-1 instead of contains

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. I stripped all the unnecessary html for easier read. Also rearranged the order of your ifs to make more sense :)

```js
function nameSubmit() {
  var nameInput = document.getElementById('nameCheck').value.trim();
  var output = document.getElementById('ans');
  if (!nameInput) {
    output.innerHTML = "Enter a name please";
  } else if (nameInput.indexOf('a') === -1) {
    output.innerHTML = "You suck!"
  } else {
    output.innerHTML = "You don't suck";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nameCheck">

<button onclick="nameSubmit()">Submit</button>

<p id="ans"></p>
```

Comment: The OP wants to say "you suck" when there is no a, and "you don't suck" when there is an a. You flipped the cases.

Comment: Then just flip the text around, geeze. Thanks mplungjan for making it simpler :)